# Invalid command 'php_admin_value'

Tags: server, apache2, php, virtualmin

When I want to start Apache2 on my Ubuntu Server, I have this error

```
AH00526: Syntax error on line 49 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/bookstyle.sokrator.net.conf:
Invalid command 'php_admin_value', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: If you're marking your own question SOLVED, please consider adding an answer to explain specific steps - you can later accept your own answer by clicking the gray checkmark next to it. This helps others and is the actual proper way to actually mark question as solved on this site.

Comment: This is posted as a comment. There's an orange button "Answer Your Question" if you scroll down. That's the appropriate method.

Comment: Thanks, I'm new here and I didn't know what should I do, thanks

Comment: No problem.  Congrats on resolving the issue and welcome to the site !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved doing this:

```
a2enmod php5.6-fpm 
service apache2 restart
```

Comment: Don't forget to also restart fpm like this: `sudo service php7.4-fpm restart`

Answer (score 2):

after upgrading 20.04 to 22.04 had this problem solved with php8.1 mod enabling

```
sudo a2enmod php8.1
```

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem after updating from PHP 7.x to PHP 8.1. The hint from s4n.ty was what we needed. However, we're using PHP via Apache module, so our solution was this:

```
sudo apt install libapache2-mod-php8.1
```